# Techniques to convert large format watercolour paintings to digital files?

Tags: file-format, scanning

What is the best way to get my watercolour paintings into a digital format for printing, and what would be the best quality?

Currently, I'm cutting them out and placing them on a green backing and then I remove the green in Photoshop... but surely there is a better way?

Comment: Your using a  camera? Why not use a scanner? Since paintings are rectangles its far better to use a neutral gray as not to get color casts.

Comment: Watercolouring your PC likely isn't a good idea ;)

Comment: Hi! Can you give some details about the size of the paintings, what size you want to print them, the type of stock you want to use for printing and printing technique, if you're taking pictures of the painting at the moment (seems so), etc. You can edit your question and add these details!

Comment: I do not understand why are you cuting them and pasting them in a green background that you are removing again!